# Ghostscript failing on batch process

Tags: vb.net, crash, ghostscript

I've got a vb.net program that runs on an overnight schedule. It loops through some folders and calls gswin64c.exe (v 9.52) as a process on each of the pdfs within. There are 5000 or so pdfs involved each time, so it takes a few hours.

I'm using a few separate calls:

Getting a report on an area of the page:

-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=(width in points) -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=(height in points) -dFIXEDMEDIA -sDEVICE=inkcov -o - -c <</BeginPage {-(start point) translate}>> setpagedevice -f (pdf name)

Converting to CMYK:

-dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOCACHE -dPDFX -dUseCIEColor -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sColorConversionStrategyForImages=CMYK  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -sOutputFile=(my file)

A bit of background:

I do the 'report' operation above a few times as I need to check the colour content in several areas of each pdf to make sure they are 'blank'. If the reports show no other colours I do a pdf cleanup and remove the text from a certain area. The CMYK conversion is only run if a pdf cleanup operation fails (I've found the fail was due to colours used in some of the graphics within the pdf I've been given and this seems to sort it out)

Both processes work fine for a while - BUT for some reason I get the following error after running a few thousand files through the vb.net program:

[image: Error message]

When this error hits the vb.net program freezes and is eventually ended by the settings I have in the windows scheduled event settings.

The problem does not seem to be with a particular pdf, and I can't see anything else running that would clash in any way with my program.

Could anyone suggest what might be going wrong?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have a search for "exception code 0xc0000005". Have you tried using the 32-bit version of Ghostscript?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I haven't tried the 32bit version, so may be worth a go - what makes you think that might work better though?  

Unfortunately the process is a bit hard to test as I've found it sometimes works and sometimes not - which points to an issue with the pdfs I'm processing I guess.

I'm going to try cutting out the CMYK conversion bit and re-test to see if I can pinpoint exactly where the problem lies. It takes a few hours to run, so this may be a long debug process....

Comment: As the error is for a memory access violation, there could be something in the 64-bit version which is different in the 32-bit version for memory access. I've seen suggestions to test the computer's RAM for that error code, if you felt like doing that.

Comment: Thanks - that's useful to know. I ran a test last night but I'd made a silly mistake in the code, so it didn't work properly. I'm becoming more convinced it's the CMYK conversion that's giving the problem so hopefully the next test will give me some answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late reply, but the issue was the CMYK conversion - it was failing and producing a corrupt file on a small minority of the pdfs I was running. I now do a quick open/close of the pdf within a try/end try to detect any problems and handle properly. Need to run more tests - only 3 out of 4500 pdfs I tested had this issue of CMYK convert resulting in corrupted file.